# How to keep a form from being submitted if not filled up using javascript?

Tags: html, forms

(I copied the code below from a tutorial but it dose not work out, and I wonder if I should do something specific on the page receiving the submitted data. )

```
<script>
function stopsubmit()
{
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click",function(event)
{
if(document.getElementById("name").value="")
{
event.preventDefault();document.getElementById("erroeMessage").innerHTML="Please write your name";return false;
}
else
{
return true;
}
}
)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use `onsubmit = "return checking()"` in your form. If it's not true, then the form isn't submited. So use `return false;` if the fields aren't proprely filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onsubmit` and `return false` to prevent submitting. A form can only have one onsubmit function though.

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();">
    <input id="aField" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
function validate() {
    if(document.getElementById("aField").value.length == 0) {
        alert("Hold it right there, buddy!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet has syntax errors, e.g.

```
if(document.getElementById("name").value="")
```

**Must double equality instead one.**

Your sample is worked in this fiddle (with my sample html):
[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/beylkhanovdamir/fqozypw3/1/)

Comment: Also you need add checking for .innerHTML property instead .value
http://jsfiddle.net/beylkhanovdamir/fqozypw3/3/